# How to solve problem showing too many fields in a form?

Tags: usability, forms, web-app

I have a form with more than 20 fields to fill and this is in a popup dialog.
What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Do you really need that many fields?  The first step to Good Design - is to reduce the number of elements; Keep only those that are really required !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing you are already using categories, and what I understand is you don't want to have scrolling inside your popup?

If your user does not need to see all the information filled into your form, depending on the process I see two options where the form fields are divided into smaller blocks (for example your categories?), **tabs** or **wizard style process**.

Many Windows applications use tabs to group settings into smaller blocks.

Example of form split into tabs: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxForm/samples/05_integration/05_split.html

Answer (score 2):

What platform would this be in? For mobile devices? For desktops?

If it is just for desktops, a box with a scroll-able region should suffice. Or if there are so many fields, then it probably deserves its own page.

For mobile devices, I think it would be preferable to group the fields into logical categories and separate them into pages

For example, a user details form could have the following categories

Basic Info

- Name
- Gender
- Age

Contact Info

- Mobile number
- Email Address
- Home Address

Comment: The app runs in desktops. The logical categorization is already in place. We don't want the user to come out of the calling screen that's the reason for choosing a popup dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of some fields depends on previous choices/answers you can populate the form accordingly (= based on previous choices) using a framework like jQuery of plain old JavaScript. But if I understand it correctly the only elements in the form are 20 fields? If so, you could try grouping similar fields and use -for example- collapsible divs? So users can finish the form group by group.

Comment: Thanks Ziepe! collapsible divs or tabs which one is better?

Comment: Personally I'd go for the divs because -in my opinion- users can be guided to the next step. For example: fill in the fields in the first div and have some sort of call to action to open the next one(s). While tabs -again in my opinion- don't oblige you to activate them.